# Asking for passwords in Jenkins pipeline files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that needs to ask for a password.

I have the following:

```
def password = input message: 'Please enter the password', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'password')]
```

The problem is that the field shows up the characters in Jenkins when I type them in meaning anyone looking over my shoulder can see them.

The value is also logged clearly in the logfile.

Is there a way that I can:

1. mask the characters as they are typed in the field?
2. hide the value in the log file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `password` parameter named ‘hidden‘ as following:

```
input message: 'enter password', parameters: [password(defaultValue: 'value', description: '', name: 'hidden')]
```